# static sections of html over multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have a web site with a media player for audio built in. Currently when I visit another page in my website the media player resets for obvious reasons (because the entire page gets loaded).

Is there any way to keep the current song that is playing in the audio player, playing while the user clicks through to a new page? The audio player is simply inside a `div` and when the user wants to play a new song the javascript just changes the audio objects `src` atribute.

Comment: Post your code what you have tried so far

Comment: You must use PHP/AJAX to load new content in container div, everithing else must be static...header, player, footer etc.

Comment: found that the best solution is using AJAX to load content into a containing div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an iframe and keep the audio player outside of it, so the user does not navigate the entire page but only in the iframe

Basic example:

```
<div id="audioplayer"></div>
<iframe src="index.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: so when the user changed the page it would only change the iframe and not the rest of the page? What i am looking to do is something like how this website does it. http://hypem.com/

Comment: That page does what you are saying, but instead of using an iframe, it uses AJAX to load all the content except the header, which contains the audio player. I just recommenden you the iframe so that you don't have to change you web structure

Comment: Ok thanks alot I really appreciate it but one last thing if you don't mind is there any way to send the iframe information where to direct itself in the url?